# Google Docs Script editor checking if a formula exists in a cell

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to check a range of cells in a row to see if one is blank, if it is, I am inserting an image, if it is not blank, I am attempting to move to the next cell in the row to check that until the range is finished.

So far I have this:

```
function gfc() {
var stockitem = '=image("imageurlhere")';
var item1 = getValue('g4');
var item2 = getValue('h4');
var item3 = getValue('i4');
if (item1 == ''); {
setValue('g4', stockitem);
}
else if (item2 == '') {
setValue('h4', stockitem);
}
else {
setValue('i4', stockitem);
}
}
```

The problem I am having is that the code works if I am inserting text, but if I am inserting the image it counts the image as a blank cell and re-inserts the image in the already image filled cell.

E.G. If I insert an image into g4 because it was blank, that image would then be counted as blank again and re-inserted without going to the next step. I know I am missing something simple, any help will do, thank you!

Comment: A side comment, it looks like you have defined functions like setValue('range') and getValue('range') to set and get single values.  It's worth mentioning that you may also want to look at using the built in range.getValues() and setValues() functions, which let you operate on more than one cell at a time via Arrays.  Your current approach limits you to one cell at a time, which will be slow if you are operating on many cells.  Generally you want to read/write from the sheet as little as is practical.

Comment: Cameron, you are correct. I had range at first that I was experimenting with, but it would set all of the cells equal to an image. I wanted to make it so that it checks one cell, if it is blank inserts the image and finishes. If it is not blank it would move to the next cell and add that there unless all of the designated cells were filled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is a separate `getFormula()` call that must use to retrieve formulas from a cell.

See: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula

Typically `getValue()` would return the result of the formula in the cell, but I suppose it doesn't return anything useful with the `=image()` formula.

Comment: Thank you very much! I knew it had to be something simple I was missing. It works perfectly.